# How to test web development for the Maple browser installed on Samsung TVs?

Tags: html, css, testing, samsung-smart-tv

We've got a job to develop a dynamic slideshow (featuring changing information) that will be displayed on a big screen Samsung TV.

The Samsung TVs run "Smart TV" which uses the "Maple" browser. Here is the best information I've found: http://webinos.org/deliverable-d026-target-platform-requirements-and-ipr/2-6-samsung-tv-tno/

We mainly develop in HTML5/CSS3 but it appears that the Maple browser doesn't support these: http://www.scribd.com/doc/51800086/139/Maple-browser

I'd like to be able to properly test our work before giving it to the client. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this without buying a big screen TV?

Comment: It's always best to test it on the real thing. Even if you find a simulator or are able to install maple on a pc to work with, it won't compare to testing on the actual unit.  I'd recommend buying one, or look at renting one for the development period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Samsung SDK you have emulator. It's not perfect, but you can test there 95% of your work ;)

You need to register there for access to downloads
http://www.samsungdforum.com/